# How to update all rows in a column with random values?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

Consider a table named **data_records** having **5 records** and **2 columns** (C1 and C2).

The goal is to update all rows of the **C2** column with a different random value for each.

The following does not work:

```
UPDATE data_records SET
  C2 = d.r
FROM
  (SELECT random() as r, generate_series(1, 5) as g) as d
```

as it update all rows of C2 with the same number.

The subquery

```
SELECT random() as r, generate_series(1, 5) as g
```

however, when performed in isolation does generate the table I want, i.e. one random value per row.

How can obtain the behavior I describe?

**UPDATE**

The reason I am trying to update with a subquery is because I have a case where my target column is of type **jsonb**. 
My SET clause looks more like this:

```
SET C2 = jsonb_set(C2, '{variation}', to_jsonb(d.r))
```

Thanks to the comments I realized that my initial question was missing a piece of rationale.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not simply `UPDATE table set C2 = random()`?

Comment: I am trying to update with a subquery because I have a case where the field I am updating is of type jsonb. So the assignment is of type SET C2 = jsonb_set(C2, '{variation}', to_jsonb(-- stuff coming from subquery using random generated data --))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=9b85583b74197e51b44e8ae619db4802)

The simple one for your JSON is:

```
UPDATE 
    data_records dr
SET 
    c2 = jsonb_set(dr.c2, '{variation}', to_jsonb(random()));
```

---

If you want the second column with the `generate_series` (for whatever) you will need something to join on the original table. `generate_series` could give you rows from `1` to `5`. So to join on the `data_records` you would need a `1` to `5` column there too. If this is what is saved in `c1` there's no problem. Simply join against `c`1.

But if not you have to generate it, maybe with a `row_number` window function which adds the row count as column. Then you are able to join the row count against the `generated_series` column and you have a row with a `random` value for each `c1` and `c2`. One of them should be unique. This unique column (`c1` in my case) works as the `WHERE` filter of the `UPDATE` clause. Of course this could be the `c2`. But if they are not unique you would end with same `random` values for same `c1/c2` values:

```
UPDATE 
    data_records dr
SET 
    c2 = jsonb_set(dr.c2, '{variation}', to_jsonb(rand.r))
FROM 
    (SELECT *, row_number() OVER () rn FROM data_records) dr_rn
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT generate_series(1, 5) gs , random() r) rand 
ON dr_rn.rn = rand.gs

WHERE dr.c1 = dr_rn.c1;
```

It would be really more simple if you would have an unique id column. But nevertheless I don't see any reasons for making this that complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do what you want:

```
UPDATE data_records
    SET C2 = random();
```

I'm not sure why you want to use a subquery or `generate_series()`.

Comment: The reason for the generate_series() comes from the fact that my case involves updating a column of type jsonb with data that comes from a subquery generating random values.

Answer (score 1):

use just `random` function no need any sub-query

```
update t
   set C2 = random()
```

Comment: Do you know of a way that I can achieve it using the subquery? Thank you.